# Does SELECT DISTINCT work with Perl's DBD::CSV?

Tags: perl, select, dbi

I found a SELECT-example on the web.
When I try it in my script I get this error-message:

`Specifying DISTINCT when using aggregate functions isn't reasonable - ignored. at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 496.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:CSV:", undef, undef, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 } );
my $table = 'artikel';

my $array_ref = [   [ 'a_nr', 'a_name', 'a_preis' ],  
            [ 12, 'Oberhemd', 39.80, ],
            [ 22, 'Mantel', 360.00, ],
            [ 11, 'Oberhemd', 44.20, ],
            [ 13, 'Hose', 119.50, ],
        ];
$dbh->do( "CREATE TEMP TABLE $table AS IMPORT(?)", {}, $array_ref );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT a_name FROM $table" );
$sth->execute();
$sth->dump_results();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Does SELECT DISTINCT not work with DBD::CSV or is something wrong with my script?

edit:
The output is

`'Oberhemd'
'Mantel'
'Oberhemd'
'Hose'
4 rows`

I thought it should be

`'Oberhemd'
'Mantel'
'Hose'
3 rows`

Installed versions:

`Perl            : 5.010000    (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  OS              : linux       (2.6.31)
  DBI             : 1.609
  DBD::Sponge     : 12.010002
  DBD::SQLite     : 1.25
  DBD::Proxy      : 0.2004
  DBD::Gofer      : 0.011565
  DBD::File       : 0.37
  DBD::ExampleP   : 12.010007
  DBD::DBM        : 0.03
  DBD::CSV        : 0.26`

Comment: You should really consider moving to perl5.10.1. It fixes a number of things that weren't quite right in 5.10.0.

Comment: Interesting. I get the warning (although working code) with Perl 5.10.0, `DBD::CSV` 0.26, `SQL::Parser` 1.23 and `DBI` 1.609. I'd be surprised to hear that perl itself is to blame.

Comment: I tried with perl v5.8.8 and get still 4 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi This is an easily reproducable bug.  SELECT data_display_mask FROM test.csv returns 200 plus rows. SELECT DISTINCT data_display_mask FROM test.csv returns the warning message and same 200 rows.

If i do an awk, sort -u for unique ( values of the row ) I get 36 values, which is what I would expect.

Certainly a bug in the code.

-Kanwar

perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.2.24-6.2.3, archname=i686-linux-thread-multi

DBD::CSV  0.26
SQL::Parser 1.23
DBI 1.609

example:

Specifying DISTINCT when using aggregate functions isn't reasonable - ignored. at /opt/perl2exe/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/SQL/Parser.pm line 496.
87060
87060
87060
87060

SQL used is SELECT DISTINCT entry_id FROM test.csv

Comment: Which appears to be fixed in later releases of SQL::Statement. 1.23 is at least 9 versions out of date and was actually removed from CPAN.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the message about something being not reasonable is

1. Only a warning. Your script works nevertheless.
2. Confusing and non-sensical: you don't use any aggregate functions.

I smell a bug in either `DBD::CSV` or `SQL::Statement`.

**Edit:** `DISTINCT` is explicitly allowed in [`SQL::Statement`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Statement::Syntax#SELECT)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $attributeName1, COUNT( $attributeName2) FROM tableName GROUP BY $attributeName1, $attributeName2");
```

this gave me: attributeName1 and a distinct count of attributeName2

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

You can turn around this problem using a `GROUP BY` statement instead of `DISTINCT`.

This is just a turn around waiting for the resolution of a bug ...

Comment: Could you post your "GROUP BY"-statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a more general phenomenon with `DBD::CSV`, namely, that it allows a lot of SQL syntax for which the meaning is silently ignored.

I have seen cases of `SELECT DISTINCT`  that actually filter out duplicates, so the case you mention here seems a bug,
but I haven't found a way to make the `DISTINCT` in `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT foo) FROM bar` do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I get 3 rows back.

```
    $ perl x.pl
'Oberhemd'
'Mantel'
'Hose'
3 rows

perl -MDBI -le 'DBI->installed_versions;'
      Perl            : 5.010001    (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
      OS              : linux   (2.6.24-28-server)
      DBI             : 1.617
      DBD::mysql      : 4.020
      DBD::Sys        : 0.102
      DBD::Sponge     : 12.010002
      DBD::SQLite     : 1.33
      DBD::Proxy      : 0.2004
      DBD::Pg         : 2.17.2
      DBD::Oracle     : 1.38
      DBD::ODBC       : 1.33
      DBD::Multiplex  : 2.014122
      DBD::Gofer      : 0.015057
      DBD::File       : 0.40
      DBD::ExampleP   : 12.014310
      DBD::DBM        : 0.06
      DBD::CSV        : 0.30
```

Added:

```
perl -MSQL::Statement -le 'print $SQL::Statement::VERSION'
1.31
```

Version 1.23, release November 20th, 2009
* Correct handling of DISTINCT in aggregate functions