# Perl - DBI::CSV sorting issue

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a text file called x.txt with the below data:

```
emailid,hits
aa,100
bb,200
cc,300
dd,400
ee,500
aa,400
```

and my perl code is

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, { f_dir => ".",csv_sep_char     => "," });

my $query = "SELECT emailid,sum(hits) tothits FROM x.txt  group by emailid order by tothits desc";
my $sth   = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print $row->{emailid},"--",$row->{tothits},"\n";

    }
$sth->finish ();
```

which returns

```
cc--300
bb--200
dd--400
aa--500
ee--700
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a line with "ee,200" too?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL looks ok. The reason the sort doesn't happen seems to be because of [limitations in DBD::CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941321/does-select-distinct-work-with-perls-dbdcsv).

I tried to see if it would work with DBD::AnyData, but that doesn't recognise `tothits` and dies.

It looks like you'll need to do a workaround, like fetchall then sort.

Comment: The limitation (omission?, bug?) is more likely in SQL::Statement.